# Rails and jQuery: accessing images

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to access images uploaded to my Rails app with jQuery, i.e., switching images out and the like. The jQuery's pretty straightforward:

```
$('#a1').change(function() {
  var src = $(this).val();
  $('#t1').html(src ? "<img src='../../images/000/000/"+src+".jpg' />":"");
});
```

I'm totally stuck when trying to use the Rails asset call with jQuery. I can call up the required images elsewhere on the page, thus:

```ruby
@a.image.url(:thumb)
```

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to answer this myself in case it helps someone. Instead of accessing the images directly with jQuery I assigned IDs to them in Rails, thus:

```
<% @articles_by_page.each do |m| %>
<%= image_tag(m.image.url(:large), :id => 'article1_thumb'+m.issue_id.to_s) %>
<% end %>
```

And subsequently handled their visibility in jQuery:

```
$('#doc_article1').change(function() {
    var src = $(this).val();
    $('#thumbs1 a').css('display', 'none');
    $('#article1_thumb'+src).css('display', 'block');
});
```

Might help someone.

Answer (score 1):

If your images are uploaded by the user, they're not "assets" in the Asset Pipeline sense. You can't use the asset helpers to serve them. Continue to use `/images/000/000/etc` to acces them.

Assets are permanent files which reside in `app/assets`. They can't be dynamically uploaded content, as the whole purpose is to precompile them for production. If the file isn't available at "compile" time when you run `rake assets:precompile`, it's not a good candidate for the asset pipeline.

Comment: It seems to me like it's inefficient to hard-code the URLs of the images to that degree. Will using `@.image.url(:thumb)` or some translation thereof not work?

Comment: I get a routing error, too, using the above method: No route matches [GET] `/images/xyz.jpg`.

Comment: You have to give it a real path to where ever you're hosting the user-uploaded images...